# Passing object through constructor or method

Tags: php

So I have an object that could hold a string which contains some data, I have to validate the object or string but I cannot think why I would pass it into the method rather than the constructor, is there certain cases when I should pass it through the constructor rather than the method or through the method rather than the constructor ?

This is PHP code.

Comment: Could you put some code? I suppose you are talking about PHP.

Comment: I haven't really got any code it's just a general question really

Comment: The question was unclear to me, because I was not able to tell if was a javascript question posted with the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor is also method differences is just in its usage. There are some things that we need to do at creation of an object of some class so for those things we pass object/setting arguments to constructor and when we need to process some data in context of that class we use method.
I think this was what u wanted to ask "difference b/w usage of method and constructor". If you got some coding issue tell me the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an object into a constructor if you need it to be saved in the object for later use by one or more methods.  Then, if you assign it, or a copy of it, to a member variable, it becomes part of the object's "state".

If the object to be passed is transient, and you only need it for the lifetime of the method, then you can pass it as an argument to the method.

Comment: I see, so it would be wrong to assign it to a property to use with multiple methods if it's been passed through a method ?

Comment: It would be redundant to pass it through a method if it's stored in a property already during construction.  It stays in the object instance for access by any method any time.  It would work, but it breaks the "encapsulation" part of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Actually, there is an oop concept known as setter injection which involves setting an object using a method other than a constructor.  It's useful when you want to avoid messing with the constructor.  So to say that it "breaks encapsulation" is not always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an arg through an object constructor has only one nominal benefit, and that is you are removing the extra step of calling setter(s) directly.

```
$foo = new Foo($dbo);

// Same thing as 
$foo = new Foo();

$foo->setDbo($dbo);
```

Personally, I prefer to call setters explicitly rather than pass them through to the constructor because I don't want to end up with 15 signature arguments, and I can see how the calling code is using the object.

From time to time, I do use constructors for preparing related objects, but never for passing arguments.